# Finding the size of a BST in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the size of a BST using this piece of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BST bst = new BST();
        int [] arr = {12, 15,7,3,81, 9};
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            bst.add(arr[i]);
        }

        System.out.print(size(bst.root));

    }
    public static int size(Node node){
        if (node != null) {
            return size(node.left) +1 + size(node.right) + 1;
        }else
            return 0;
    }
```

The answer I get is 12, which is the first element.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting 12 is that your code returns twice the number of elements in the tree (of which there are 6). The fact that 12 also happens to be the first element is purely a coincidence.

The `return` statement should read:

```
return 1 + size(node.left) + size(node.right);
```

i.e. this node plus the size of the left subtree plus the size of the right subtree.

The second `+1` you have is erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

You are double-counting.  Only one `+1` is necessary here.